# Dual Boot Issue 18.04: HDD Partition cant find after log off

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with dual boot. I installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04. But ***Problem is When I log out my laptop I cant find my other HDD partitions.*** in my files and other locations section. I restarted my laptop while this problem. Then Everything is okay. But WHen I used Ubuntu 16.04, I couldn't find the similar issue. How can I solve this problem? any idea how I cant fix this problem?

Comment: Where can't you find your partitions? Where are you expecting them to be present?

Comment: in my file files sections.